# Find all analytics functions in the domain $\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C}. |z|< R\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Find all analytics functions in the domain $\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C}; |z|< R\}$ that satisfy $f(0)=e^{i}$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for each $z\in\Omega$.

I try to write a series,i.e., $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{n}z^{n}}$, then $f(0)=a_{0}=e^{i}$, but I do not get any result. Any help please !

Comment: What is $|f(0)|$?

Comment: The value is $\vert f(0)\vert=1$, and that implies that?

Comment: Ever heard of the maximum principle for analytic functions?

Comment: "Let $f$ be a function holomorphic on some connected open subset $D$ of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and taking complex values. If $z_{0}$ is a point in D such that: $\vert f(z_{0})\vert\geq\vert f(z)\vert$ for all $z$ in a neighborhood of $z_{0}$, then the function $f$ is constant on $D$". Then $\Omega$ is connected and if $z_{0}=0\in\Omega$ such that $\vert f(0)\vert=1\geq\vert f(z)\vert$ for all $z\in\Omega$, then $f$ is constant on $\Omega$, is this correct?

Comment: That's the right argument. Now you know all functions with this property.

Comment: Apology look like an idiot , but I don't know that function is.

Comment: Then f is constant, but when I use the fact that $\vert z\vert<R$?? Regards

Comment: The function is constant and you know its value at one point. The fact z| < R$ implies that this function is defined on an open connected set as required.